# Finite state transducer that multiplies numbers

Tags: formal-languages, transducers

How is possible to construct a finite state transducer that multiplies a number by 5? We can assume that numbers are supplied in binary notation, from least significant bits to most significant.

Comment: Do you know how to multiply by 2? By 3?

Comment: How are the numbers encoded?

Comment: We can assume that numbers are supplied in binary notation, from least significant bits to most significant.

Comment: Can you multiply by 2? By 3?

Comment: I don't really understand how to multiply by other numbers

Comment: Do you know how to add 1? Do you know how to do any kind of operation using a finite state transducer?

Comment: I understand how you can add 1, like any other constant.

Comment: Can you multiply by 2?

Comment: I don't understand how to use arithmetic operations other than addition, and possibly subtraction...

Comment: If you don't know how to multiply by 2, you won't be able to multiply by 5. I suggest starting with multiplying by 2, then moving on to multiplying by 3, then by 4, and only then by 5.

Comment: Okay. Can you give a hint how I can multiply by 2?

Comment: No. That's something you should be able to work out on your own.

Comment: I got an idea how to multiply by 2, it's just a one-bit shift and it is quite obvious how to implement this using a tranduser. In the case of multiplication by 3, I thought it was multiplication by 2 + addition with a number. But it seems to me that in the case of multiplying by 3, I can come up with something better. Can you tell me which way to think next?

Comment: If you can multiply by 3 by simulating x+2x, then you can multiply by 5 by simulating x+4x.

Comment: Well, the transition to multiplication by five is quite understandable. I am interested in whether I proposed the correct idea for multiplying by 3. If I use my idea to build a converter, you get a rather cumbersome construction. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: I don't know if there's a more direct way, but this way really isn't too bad. It's just a bit of work. Sometimes you have to get your hands dirty.

Comment: When you work it out, please consider answering your own question.